# Day Button and Week Button is not displayed

Tags: angularjs, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I am using fullcalendar with angularjs to display events. Currently the month view is working correctly. But **day button** and **week button** aren't displayed in the UI.In both Left and right side Only Today, back and next buttons are displayed.I can't figure out the reason for that. Please find the below code.

view.html

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../fullcalendar-4.1.0/packages/core/main.css"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../fullcalendar-4.1.0/packages/daygrid/main.css"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../fullcalendar-4.1.0/packages/list/main.css"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../fullcalendar-4.1.0/packages/timegrid/main.css"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../fullcalendar-4.1.0/packages/core/main.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../fullcalendar-4.1.0/packages/daygrid/main.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../fullcalendar-4.1.0/packages/timegrid/main.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../fullcalendar-4.1.0/packages/list/main.js"></script>
</head>
<script>
$scope.event = {events: [{
            title:'test1',
            start: '2019-05-05 08:00',
            end: '2019-05-10 08:00'
          },
          {
            title:'test2',
            start: '2019-05-05 12:00'
        }]};
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

        var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
            events: $scope.event.events,
            plugins: [ 'dayGrid','timeGrid','list' ],
            header: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
}
        });
        calendar.render();
    });
</script>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
   <div id="calendar" ng-model="eventSources"></div>    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add the following code lines in your script to display the day view and week view.

```
header: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'dayGridMonth,dayGridWeek,timeGridDay'
}
```

Reason for changing the right property fields is agendaWeek,agendaDay words aren't supported in the latest release of FullCalendar

Comment: 'dayGridMonth,dayGridWeek,dayGridDay' if you're on 4.3.1